# Deconvoluting function results in R

Tags: r

I have a dataset consisting of two groups and I want to look at the correlation of Age with all my independent variables for those two groups, g1 and g2.  Eventually, I'll want to plot the results to compare the correlation values I receive for the two groups.

So far, I've done this:

```
corg1 = data.frame('rho'=rep(NA,length(vars)),'p.value'=rep(NA,length(vars)))
#vars = list of variables I'm interested in

corg1$rho = apply(data[g1,vars],2,function (x) { cor.test(x,data$Age[g1],method='spearman')$estimate })
corg1$p.value = apply(data[g1,vars],2,function (x) {cor.test(x,data$Age[g1],method='spearman')$p.value})
```

Then I repeat the process for g2 with a different data frame receiving the results.

```
corg2 = data.frame('rho'=rep(NA,length(vars)),'p.value'=rep(NA,length(vars)))
#vars = list of variables I'm interested in

corg2$rho = apply(data[g2,vars],2,function (x) { cor.test(x,data$Age[g2],method='spearman')$estimate })
corg2$p.value = apply(data[g2,vars],2,function (x) {cor.test(x,data$Age[g2],method='spearman')$p.value})
```

This gives me 2 data frames that I assume are ordered similarly, which seems safe enough, but it seems unnecessary to run cor.test twice and strip off the piece that I want.  I could also use just one data frame to capture all the results - two columns for g1 and two columns for g2.  Still, I'm sure I'm missing something.

I would appreciate any suggestions to make this more R-like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

something like:

```
results <- apply(data,2,function (x) { 
    ctg1 <- cor.test(x[g1,vars],data$Age[g1],method='spearman')
    ctg2 <- cor.test(x[g2,vars],data$Age[g2],method='spearman')
    c(rho1 = ctg1$estimate, rho2 = ctg2$estimate, p.value1 = ctg1$p.value, p.value2 = ctg2$p.value)
  }
)
```

you can just do `cor.test()` once for each variable combo and extract the parts you need. `apply()` will stick things into a matrix for you. (you may need to pass in `g1`, `g2` and `vars` as well)

Comment: Perfect!  Makes perfect sense but I couldn't come up with that one.  Thank you.